# How to solve Typescript import module problem

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have split my code into several projects. And now trying to import the modules, located in *node_modules*.

**import Ticker from "ticker"** // Typescript not complaining
But the transpiled JS *"import Ticker from "ticker;"* does, module spec missing ‘./’, ‘../’ of ‘/’.

But adding "./" leads to: *"Cannot find module '.ticker' or its corresponding type declarations."*

**import {Ticker} from "./node_modules/ticker/dist/ticker.js"**, results in a working application.
But Typescript complains "Could not find a declaration file for module './node_modules/ticker/dist/ticker.js'. "

Even if I use
*///< reference path='node_modules/ticker/typings/ticker.d.ts' / >*

The ticker project package contains

```
  "main": "dist/ticker.js",
  "module": "dist/ticker.js",
  "typings": "typings/ticker.d.ts",
```

**ticker.d.ts**

```
declare module 'ticker' {
    class Ticker {
        constructor (container:HTMLElement);
        add (htmlElem:HTMLElement):number;
    }
    export default Ticker;
}
```

The main project *tsconfig.json* contains:

```
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "Ticker":["/node_modules/ticker/dist/ticker.js"]
    },
```

I'm using only **tsc** and getting confused by all provided options and possibilities.

Why does VCode recognize the path *"import {Ticker} from "./node_modules/ticker/ticker"*, pointing to the location of *ticker.ts*.
But not *"./node_modules/ticker/dist/"*, pointing to the *ticker.js*?

Comment: *"I have split my code into several projects. And now trying to import the modules, located in node_modules"* Why is your code in `node_modules`? That's unusual. Third-party modules go there, but the modules for your own app (the one you're writing the code for) usually don't.

Comment: Have you looked at another node module how they are set up? I would emulate their structure and configs. Is "ticker" a real node module? If yes you can set up post-install scripts to write configs, build to `dist/` etc.

Comment: The base project consists of a NodeJS data web crawler/scraper, a NodeJS data server (API's), and front-end dashboard applications. Multiple uses, project and thus code re-usage. Different sub-projects and maintainers.

Comment: " Is "ticker" a real node module?", no! A web component (HTML dashboard).
Other sub-projects are Node applications.